# Using conditional statements with styled components

Tags: css, reactjs, styled-components

I'm trying to style my PaymentBtn which includes my main styled Button but I only want the hover effect to be affected when my isLoading prop is activated while keeping everything the same EXCEPT the hover effect. Is there a way to only change the styling on the hover effect?

Basic button

```
export const BaseBtn = styled.button`
  min-width: 165px;
  width: auto;
  height: 50px;
  letter-spacing: 0.5px;
  line-height: 50px;
  padding: 0 35px 0 35px;
  font-size: 15px;
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-family: "Open Sans Condensed";
  font-weight: bolder;
  border: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;

  &:hover {
    background-color: white;
    color: black;
    border: 1px solid black;
  }
`;
```

PaymentBtn styles

```
export const PaymentBtn = styled(Button)`
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-top: 30px;
`;
```

I want something like this but don't know how to use it with styled-components

```
export const PaymentBtn = styled(Button)`
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-top: 30px;

&:hover {
 ${({isLoading}) => isLoading ? 
  hover:{
    background-color: "gray" : "black"
  }
}
`;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this:

```
export const PaymentBtn = styled(Button)`
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-top: 30px;

  &:hover { 
    background-color: ${props => (props.isLoading ? 'gray' : 'black')}
  }
`;
```

This will show `gray` color on hover when `isLoading` is true, otherwise, it will show `black`. If you don't want any color on `false`, set it as `transparent`.

Comment: I did find a way to figure it out, but your solution is a lot better! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
export const BaseBtn=styled.button<{isLoading:boolean}>`
....
  isLoading && ::hover{
    background-color: gray;
....
  }
`
```

I think this might work

Comment: I really appreciate the help, but it didn't work :-/

Answer (score 0):

I actually did find a method that works and I would love to hear from others with your solution

```
const PaymentBtnHover = css`
  &:hover {
    background-color: gray;
  }
`;
export const PaymentBtn = styled(Button)`
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-top: 30px;

  ${({ isLoading }) => isLoading && PaymentBtnHover}
`;
```